# bike keyhole broken

Tags: road-bike, lock

I had parked my bike outside my local grocery store and when I came out I saw that my lock had been tampered with. The keyhole where I insert my key was broken in half and the rubber coating was also cut down. Luckily I managed to haul it back to home but can't open the lock now.

How can I get it open?

Edit:it was a u lock and I got it open with a set of bolt cutters but now when I tried to ride I saw a plate on my chain broken and the removal pin on the bike chain tool that I have is also broken any way I can fix it?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Nihal. Can you explicitly state your question (use the edit button) please?

Comment: As the lock has been rendered unusable anyway, no need to be gentle. Depending on what kind of lock it is, us a bolt cutter or an angle grinder. And be happy that your lock has done it's job, you still have the bike.

Comment: You can haul it to a locksmith, or you can use a bolt cutter or angle grinder as stated.  We can't advise you further without knowing what kind of lock it is -- cable, chain, U-bolt?

Comment: Hacksaw is an option too with the right blade. but if the lock is ruined, just save yourself the money and cut it off yourself.

Comment: Well, you'll probably need to replace the chain, or at least a few links.  And, unfortunately, having the pin break on a chain tool (especially a cheap one) is not unusual.

Comment: Thank you for all your suggestions guys it really helped.I replaced the whole chain BTW

Answer (score 1):

It depends what kind of lock you have. If it took a thief a failed attempt I assume it's a good one, so take it to a locksmith or anyone with power tools, preferably with a proof of ownership of the bike.

The harder it is to destroy, the more convinced you should be that you should buy the exact same lock again :)